# How to store and invoke later, the member functions of different classes, which are inherited from the same interface class

Tags: c++, qt, functor

I am creating an application, which can be extended by several plugins that are inherited from an interface class (called AppInterface) and loaded by Qt's plugin loader system, for now. A global static instance of a class considered as the core, is made available for every plugins, using a dll.

Now to the point, to exchange datas between the plugins, I am planning to create 2 functions in the core, one to store the listener function pointers under a key in a map, and the another to invoke the stored functions
under the key, with the arguments to them.

```
std::map<char*,std::list<void*> > listenerMap;
template<typename... Args, typename T>
void listen(char* key,  T *inst, void (T::*listenerSlot)(Args...))
{
get the functor list with key from the listener map and append the functor.
}
template<typename ...Args> 
void broadcast (char* key, Args... args)
{
get the list with key from the listener map and invoke all the functors with the given arguments.
}
```

I haven't found a way to store the functor along with its class object, and invoke them later. The functor parameters are not fixed, they will vary from function to function, unless they are under the same key in the listener map.

Any changes to the structure of the broadcast and listen functions, or better ideas to invoke the stored member functions?

Or can I make use of the AppInterface, which is inherited by every plugins?

NB: I have decided not to use the Qt signal slot system , because I want the AppInterface to be the base class instead of QObject, for several reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to rely on name to know which argument to pass, so plugins should know how other plugins name their method and which argument to pass...

Then it seems simpler to provide a way to retrieve plugins:

```
AppInterface* GetPlugin(const char* name);
```

and up to the plugin to `dynamic_cast` it to the one wanted and call directly any method on it. For example:

```
struct SomePlugin : AppInterface
{
    // ...
    void print();
    int foo(int n);
};

struct MyPlugin : AppInterface
{
    // ...
    void bar() {
        auto* plugin = dynamic_cast<SomePlugIn>(GetPlugin("SomePlugIn"));

        if (plugin) {
             plugin->print();
             int n = plugin->foo(42);
             // ...
        }
    }
};
```

With some convention as `static const char* Plugin::Name`, you might provide the dynamic_cast in the function directly:

```
template <typename Plugin>
Plugin* GetPlugin() { return dynamic_cast<Plugin>(GetPlugin(Plugin::Name)); }
```

If you really want to keep your interface to register function and call them, you might use `std::any` :/

```
std::map<std::string, std::any> listenerMap;

template<typename Sig>
void register(const char* key, std::function<Sig> f);
{
    listenerMap[key] = f;
}

template<typename Sig, typename ...Args> 
void broadcast(const char* key, Args&& ... args)
{
     auto it = listenerMap.find(key);
     if (it != listenerMap.end()) {
         auto* f = std::any_cast<std::function<Sig>>(&it->second);
         if (f) {
              (*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
         }
     }
}
```

With usage similar to:

```
struct MyPlugin : AppInterface
{
    // ...
    void print() const;
    void foo(int) const;

    void my_register() {
         register<void()>("my_print", [this](){ this->print(); });
         register<void(int)>("foo", [this](int n){ this->foo(n); });
    }

    void call_me() {
        broadcast<void()>("my_print");
        broadcast<void(int)>("foo", 42);
    }

};
```

You should pass `Sig` to `broadcast` and not let deduction from `Args` for security.
Passing `std::string&` instead of `const std::string&` or `const char*` instead of `std::string` would make change expected `std::function<void(const std::string&)>` to `std::function<void(std::string&)>` and so `std::any_cast` would fail.

Comment: Is it possible to invoke the method of an object, using the method name and the x1appinterface object by dynamic_cast? The method is a member of the derived class (ie the plugin), which is unknown to the broadcaster plugin.

Comment: Also I started to try the 2nd method you have suggested. How should I call the register function say, print(int), from the listener plugin? I tried like, core->register("score",STD::bind(&AppListener::print, this, std:: placeholder_1)  but not compiled.

Comment: @RamzyValiyakath: Add usages for both methods.